# Hilbert tree: Does anyone know where to find a code implementation of this?

Tags: data-structures

I'm looking for the code or even a visual demo on how this tree works.
I have read [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~christos/PUBLICATIONS.OLDER/vldb94.pdf) on Hilbert R-Trees and tried to implement the algorithms stated

I get lost when I have to adjust the tree with the sets, as well as not sure on most other things.

It doesn't matter what language if there is an implementation as it will be used to build a C# implementation and I will be using it for reference.

Its for moving points with boundaries, that needs to have very fast insert and update calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these links for a R-Tree demo

http://gis.umb.no/gis/applets/rtree2/jdk1.1/

http://gist.cs.berkeley.edu/libgist-2.0/amdb_demo.html

http://donar.umiacs.umd.edu/quadtree/points/rtrees.html

cheers

Comment: Thanks for the links, the first one was really good, once I got used to the interface. Showed me that I didn't want what I thought I wanted at all.

I'm off to investigate the various types of quadtree variants.

Comment: oops, I meant the last one:  http://donar.umiacs.umd.edu/quadtree/points/pointquad.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an Hilbert tree, this might help:
https://code.google.com/p/uzaygezen/

If you need a spatial index with fast delete/insert capabilities, have a look at the [PH-tree](http://www.phtree.org). It partly based on quadtrees but faster and more space efficient.

Btw, the Hilbert curve is a space filling curve. The PH-Tree also uses a space filling curve internally, however it does not use the Hilbert curve but the z-curve (Morton order) which is much easier to calculate.